# How to use Intel C++ Compiler with CUDA nvcc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, intel, nvcc

I'm using NVIDIA CUDA 4.1 on Microsoft Visual studio 2008.
I also have Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011 Installed.

By default, NVIDIA's C Compiler `nvcc.exe` uses Microsoft's C Compiler `cl.exe` to compile its C code.

How can I change the settings so that `nvcc` uses Intel's C Compiler `icl.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot (or at least its HIGHLY unrecommended). The only compiler supported on windows is visual studio. Unless something has changed and they now support intel's compilers i wouldn't suggest using them

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=153975

Comment: Maybe now something has changed? Or until the only way - in my exe-program(ICC) use dll-files(MSVC + CUDA)?

Comment: @Alex.. nope. `icl` is still not supported.