# Intel C++ Composer and CUDA

Tags: cuda, icc

I create a default CUDA project in VisualStudio2008. It works OK for the MS compiler. When I try the Intel C++ Composer, it fails as showed in the following:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: testCUDA, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate files and output files for project 'testCUDA', configuration 'Debug|Win32'.
1>Compiling with CUDA Build Rule... (Microsoft VC++ Environment)
1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\bin\nvcc.exe"  -G   -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi  /MT  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\include" -maxrregcount=0   --compile -o "Debug/kernel.cu.obj" kernel.cu  
1>nvcc : fatal error : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
1>Project testCUDA : error: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling with CUDA Build Rule..."
1>Build log was saved at "file://C:\Users\JSC\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\testCUDA\testCUDA\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>testCUDA - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s), 0 remark(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My platform is win7(32bit) with CUDA5.0. I use the Intel C++ compiler with version form 11.1 to Composer XE 2011 and even Composer XE 2013. All the versions of Intel C++ compiler will provide the error information.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Currently, Intel compilers are not supported by nvcc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9434232/1231073).

Comment: According to the CUDA 5.0 release notes, ICC Compiler 12.1 is supported under 64-bit Linux: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [The CUDA 5.0 Release Notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#supported-operating-systems), on Windows only Visual C++ 9.0/10.0 compilers are supported.

On Linux only GCC is supported (see the link above for specific versions).