# NVCC cannot work with Intel's Compiler?

Tags: c++, cuda, intel, nvcc

I am trying to do some coding on GPU, and I have visual studio and intel composer installed, when I start a CUDA Project, wrote the code then compile, everything will be fine if I ask MS's compiler to compile the host code, however if I ask intel's compiler to do that, it will always fail, is there anyway to let NVCC work with intel's C++ compiler (v 13.0)?

Comment: [Currently, Intel compilers are not supported by nvcc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433722/how-to-use-intel-c-compiler-with-cuda-nvcc)

Comment: @sgar91 That's too bad, I am trying to write a library which include both cuda subroutines and Intel's optimized subroutines, it seems that the two cannot be packed together then.

Comment: Try this: Compile each file separately. cu files with `nvcc` and other files with `icl`. Then link all the object files which are created as the output of compilation.

Comment: Sure, but I cannot use the optimized routines freely on the host part this way like I thought, anyway thanks.